# Spring JAVA -> Mysql issue java

Tags: java, mysql, spring, mysql-connector

When I execute the query in mysql from java code I can't get any result set. However when I execute it from terminal I can get the result set.

Here is my code:

```
         String querys = "select USERNAME,PASSWORD,USER_ID from user_manager where username =? and password=?"
         return jdbcTemplate.query(querys, new Object[]{bean.getuname(), bean.getpword()},
              new ResultSetExtractor<Integer>() {
                   @Override
                   public Integer extractData(ResultSet rs) throws SQLException, DataAccessException {
                   while (rs.next()) {

                  logger.info("User Bean===>[" + loginbean.toString() + "]");
                return 1;
            }
            logger.info("outside  while  unsuccess ");
            return -1;
        }
    });
```

In logs I can view the username and password but i always got the log "outside  while  unsuccess"

However when I change the jar version from 8.0.16 to 5.1.6 the code run perfectly. Why version 8 doesn't work?

Comment: Can you share the query with us?

Comment: Here is the query                                                                                                                                                       String querys = "select USERNAME,PASSWORD,USER_ID from user_manager where username =? and password=?"; Query is fine same query is executed on terminal